# Software to Transfer files from one PC to another PC

Tags: windows, data-transfer

I'm looking for software to transfer files from one laptop to another laptop.

- For Windows.
- Free or Premium is Fine.

Earlier I used ShareIT, but it is very slow with different laptop models.

I've been searching around the Internet for a while but I have not been able to find any other application/software/method to transfer large files.

Comment: "`Earlier I used ShareIT.`" - why don't you use it now?

Comment: It is very slow with different laptop models, I don't know why. Slows down the performance of the PC.

Comment: Are the laptops connected via some sort of cable, for instance USB? Are they on the same LAN? Can they reach each other by IP address? Please answer then ask us to reopen, thanks :-)

Comment: If the 2 devices are in the same house/network windows file sharing is easy.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done many file transfers lately but [Robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) works well if you are happy to work from a command prompt or batch file.

Robocopy is included in all versions of Windows since Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008.

Official instructions are at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this, that it is difficult to know where to start.

Fastest might be an external hard-drive.

Simplest is just to create a Windwos Work Group or Home Group and create a network drive (e.g drive D: on one laptop is seen as drive x: on the other) and just copy.

You can "remote into" one laptop from the other. Personalty, I love [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/), which is free (anmd cross-platform, although you don't need that (yet)):

> TightVNC is a free remote control software package. With TightVNC, you can see the desktop of a remote machine and control it with your local mouse and keyboard, just like you would do it sitting in the front of that computer. TightVNC is:
>
> free for both personal and commercial usage, with full source code available,
>      useful in administration, tech support, education, and for many other purposes,
>      cross-platform, available for Windows and Unix, with Java client included,
>      compatible with standard VNC software, conforming to RFB protocol specifications.
>
> With TightVNC, you can:
>
> cut your expenses and save your time on traveling,
>      help your friends and family to solve problems with their computers remotely,
>      make sure nothing wrong is happening on your computers when you are away.

It has a very easy to use file transfer mechanism built in.

There are many, many, more ways (such as FTP), but those are the simplest.